# What are all the good music players available in ubuntu?

Tags: mp3, mp3-player

i am looking for a replacement of rhythmbox music player; please suggest some of the good music good players.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Comment: alright Jorge, please close the question i will post the question on Ubuntu forums. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhythmbox is good but not as compare to Clementine or Amarok music player.. Though Amarok is KDE app but works well even on GNOME.. Clementine is also very fine tuned music player give a try

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Banshee or maybe Audacious.

Answer (score 1):

VLC is one of the best players for Ubuntu. It can play virtually any audio or video file.